# My Android Application Stops Working When Swiping Back and Forth The Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android-viewpager, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have created an Android application which includes 44 fragments that user can swipe through them using a ViewPager and each fragment contains a high quality image (1024*768, with 240dpi). Everything works fine in this app and each page loads without any problem. However, if you swipe through the fragments, after a few ones, the app crashes and throws "OutOfMemoryError". I have noticed, when swiping back, the previous fragments will be created again, and as long as you swipe back and forth through pages, same fragments will be created over and over again! Still I'm not sure what makes this error throwed and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tries and errors, I finally managed to find my answer. Apparently "OutOfMemmoryError" is a common problem when using ViewPages with a large number of pages (fragments), specially if they consist of high quality images. But The answer simply is, that you have to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. The latter is suitable when you have small numbers of fragments, because it creates and keeps all the fragments in the memory, therefore the more fragments you have, chances are your application will throw an "OutOfMemotyError". In contrast, FragmentStatePagerAdapters are ideal for large numbers of fragments, because they destroy a fragment after it is showed and therefore use less of memory size.